# Factory Reset NYX mobile Android 4.0

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, factory-reset, hard-reset

I have a Nyx Ice Cream Sandwich tablet, running Android 4.0. I need to do a factory reset, but I'm still not able to do it. How do I do it?

I'm able to get the little android man with the red triangle and exclamation mark.

Thank You guys!

Answer (score 0):

Can you still boot normally? If yes, you can just go to `Settings > Backup & Reset > Factory data reset`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing volume up or down button after that exclamation mark?
It gives you recovery options from where you can reset your phone.